# How is (**) obtained from (*) in deriving the equivalence between average costs?

Tags: reinforcement-learning

How is (**) obtained from (*) in deriving the equivalence between average costs?[image]

Comment: Do you have the definition of $d_\pi(s)$? because what I've noticed is that in (\*\*) figures $d_\pi(s')$ over next state $s'$, while in (\*) is over $s$ - in fact it also says "after one-step transition" so, maybe, it just starts at the next timestep.